# Discrepancy between lagged lm() and lagsarlm()

Tags: r, spatial

If we have a spatial autoregressive process, we can estimate a model to control for the autoregression with a spatial lag,
$$y=\rho W y + X\beta + \epsilon$$
Where $\rho$ is the strength of the spatial correlation, and $W$ is a matrix of spatial weights. The `spdep` package for R contains the `lagsarlm` command which is designed to estimate precisely this model. The package contains methods for creating the weights. But there seems to be some discrepancy between the model fit between `lagsarlm()` and `lm()` fitted to what should be a similar model.

As an example, consider the example given with `?lagsarlm` in R.

```
library(spdep)
data(oldcol)
COL.lag <- lagsarlm(CRIME ~ INC + HOVAL, data=COL.OLD,
                nb2listw(COL.nb, style="W"), method="eigen", quiet=TRUE)
summary(COL.lag)
Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-37.68585  -5.35636   0.05421   6.02013  23.20555 

Type: lag 
Coefficients: (asymptotic standard errors) 
             Estimate Std. Error z value  Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) 45.079251   7.177347  6.2808 3.369e-10
INC         -1.031616   0.305143 -3.3808 0.0007229
HOVAL       -0.265926   0.088499 -3.0049 0.0026570

Rho: 0.43102, LR test value: 9.9736, p-value: 0.001588
Asymptotic standard error: 0.11768
    z-value: 3.6626, p-value: 0.00024962
Wald statistic: 13.415, p-value: 0.00024962
```

We can estimate what (I think) should be the same model by computing the actual spatial lag variable,

```
crime.lag <- lag.listw(nb2listw(COL.nb, style="W"), COL.OLD$CRIME)
linearlag <- lm(CRIME ~ crime.lag + INC + HOVAL, data=COL.OLD)
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-38.644  -6.103   0.266   6.563  21.610 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 38.18099    9.21531   4.143 0.000149 ***
crime.lag    0.55733    0.15029   3.709 0.000570 ***
INC         -0.86584    0.35541  -2.436 0.018864 *  
HOVAL       -0.26358    0.09136  -2.885 0.005986 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 10.12 on 45 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.6572, Adjusted R-squared: 0.6343 
F-statistic: 28.75 on 3 and 45 DF,  p-value: 1.543e-10
```

The two models, which I think should be identical, are in fact significantly different from each other in every parameter and in model fit (with the `linearlag` model providing significantly lower AIC). Are there reasons why this should be? Why should I just not use the second model and abandon the special methods?

Comment: They aren't the same! See [Land & Deane, 1992](http://www.jstor.org/stable/270997).

Comment: This makes sense. My prior research hadn't made it clear that the spatial lag was significantly different from a time-series lag. Great reference, by the way.

Comment: You should put this in an answer, explaining how ML or 2SLS methods are needed for this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OLS estimate of the spatial effect, $\rho \cdot Wy$ in your original formulation, as specified in your `linearlag` model is inconsistent. This subsequently biases the other estimates, and Land & Deane (1992) cite some simulation evidence that suggests as $\rho$ increases, the variance of the other $\beta$ estimates tend to increase (which is what you observe in your example). Land & Deane (1992) provide an alternative two-stage least square approach, using the independent variables as instruments to estimate the spatial effect (this is actually in the same `spdep` package, see the `stsls` command).

The other approach, which is conducted in `lagsarlm`, is to first estimate the spatial effect via maximum likelihood, then fit the *feasible* generalized least square model with the *given estimate* of the spatial effect (this is sometimes called a pseudo maximum likelihood approach). Land & Deane (1992) also give multiple references that derive the maximum likelihood estimate, but the only one I have read is the derivation provided in chapter 6 of Anselin (1988). See the [spdep documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spdep/spdep.pdf) for a brief description of the operation.

The inconsistency can be intuitively described based on the fact that spatial models are by their nature reciprocal. The $y$ and $Wy$ are on both sides of the equation, and so one would expect that simply including $Wy$, that is specifically the vector resulting from the spatial weights matrix post-multiplied by $y$ (what the references provided call the "population potentials") on the right hand side of the equation is correlated with the error term.

Not sure I can provide any brief intuition why EGLS or two stage least squares solve these problems (beyond if you know already how two stage least squares works), so the best I can say is to check out the references provided.

---

## Citations

- Anselin, Luc. 1988. *[Spatial Econometrics: Methods and Models](http://books.google.com/books?id=3dPIXClv4YYC)*. Kluwer. Netherlands.
- Land Kenneth & Glenn Deane. 1992. On the large-sample estimation of regression models with spatial- or network-effects terms: A two-state least squares approach. [*Sociological Methodology* 22: 221-248](http://www.jstor.org/stable/270997).